# Why I don't get the EOF?

Tags: c, eof

This is my code example. I wrote the question in my comment:

```
main(){
    long cnt; // chars count
    int c;

    /* Why the 'for' cicle doesn't finish when I input the
     * "a^Z" string and press ENTER? At this case '^Z' is
     * CTRL + Z (i.e this is EOF). I expected the second loop
     * will get the EOF (i.e. -1), but it has 26 instead of. Why?
     */
    for(cnt = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++cnt)
        ;

    printf("Chars count: %ld", cnt);
}
```

If I put `a`, `ENTER`, `CTRL` + `Z`, `ENTER` then I get the expected result: the `CTRL` + `Z` breaks the loop.

**UPD**

When I read info about `getchar` function then I saw that it uses *the line-buffered input*. It expects `ENTER` for pushing the data. I didn't see info that it *also* can push data when it get the `Ctrl - Z`. Therefore I expected that the second value will be `EOF` in my case (and the loop will be broken), i.e. I expectet that my string line will be parsed like the `a`, `EOF`, `\n` sequence.

Comment: Why have you got a semi-colon after your loop?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson the use of the loop is limted to increment `cnt`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: `ctrl^z` will do that

Comment: ctrl-z is a terminal handled thing probably. It may not do anything if there are still characters on the line.

Comment: Because the `Ctrl-Z` must be the first key entry, or the first after a `newline`.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson because its body is empty. All what I need it does in the head.

Comment: Changing loop code to `for(cnt = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++cnt) { printf("%ld %d\n", cnt, c); fflush(stdout); }` would enhance the understanding of code functionality.

Comment: @AnT Hmm... but my program doesn't get the input until I press `Enter`. So, I see the `Ctrl-Z` doesn't push my data. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @chux I get this output: `a^Z`, `0 97`, `1 26`. And the loop is not broken.

Comment: What happens when you try the input sequence of [this good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41047963/2410359)?  `A`, `Crtl Z`, `Enter`, `Crtl Z`?

Comment: What is unclear about the title question "Why I don't get the EOF?" is  you do get EOF when you type "a, ENTER, CTRL + Z, ENTER".  When you type "a ^Z  ENTER", that  does not include  the correct terminal's EOF sequence indication.  C does not define the sequence.  It is platform dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press <kbd>a</kbd>+  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>Z</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>Z</kbd> flushes the input (`stdin`) and the next input is `\n`, which is not an `EOF`. You need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>Z</kbd>  twice to simulate the second `EOF`.

Comment: I still don't understand... The `\n` value is `10`, but I get the `26`.

Comment: @AndreyBushman how do you check?

Comment: I look the values in the *Watch* window in MS Visual Studio.

Comment: When I read info about `getchar` function then I saw that it uses the *line-buffered input*. It expects `ENTER` for pushing the data. I didn't see info that it also can push data when it get the `Ctrl - Z`. Therefore I expected that the second value will be `EOF`.

Comment: I added the *UPD* section in my question.